# Why does scalac not believe that a method does not fit the required type signature?

Tags: scala, types

Why does this not compile?
The error given is `class SomeElement needs to be abstract, since method eval in trait Element of type [T <: Typed]=> scala.util.Try[T] is not defined`

I cannot understand why the method `eval` defined on SomeElement does not satisfy the type constraints.

As I understand it, `eval` should return something wrapped in a `Try` which subclasses `Typed`. 
Try is covariant in its type parameter. The implementation of `eval` in `SomeElement` returns a `NumberLike`, and `NumberLike` subclasses `Typed`. So what's gone wrong?

```
import scala.util.Try

trait Element {
   def eval[T <: Typed]: Try[T]
}

trait Typed

case class NumberLike(n: Long) extends Typed

case class SomeElement(n: Long) extends Element {
  def eval = Try {
    NumberLike(n)
  }
}

object app extends Application {
  println (SomeElement(5).eval)
}
```

Trying to add an explicit type parameter to eval in `SomeElement` doesn't help either:

```
case class SomeElement(n: Long) extends Element {
  def eval[NumberLike] = Try {
    NumberLike(n)
  }
}
```

Changing the defintion of SomeElement to the above gives:

```
  found   : <empty>.NumberLike
  required: NumberLike(in method eval)
    NumberLike(n)
```

**EDIT** I would really like to know **why** this doesn't compile. Workarounds for the problem are helpful, but I really want to know what's going on here.

Comment: I can't write a full answer now, but definitely, you can't override / implement poly function with type parameter by function without it; so you have to write smth like `def eval[T: NumberLike] = ...`

Comment: Why `abstract trait`?

Comment: Any sense in it? For me `trait` or `sealed trait` is sufficient.

Comment: Abstract doesn't actually do anything on traits, so I guess not. Not that it changes anything.

Comment: That's the point, why adding something of no use? Except lessen the readbility?

Comment: @MrBones hm, have no compiler now, think it is possible to make a dependent type:  `trait Element { type T <:  Typed;  def eval[T]: Try[T] = ... ` and in child classes just implement desired type `type T = NumberLike; def eval =...`

Comment: @DaunnC Why we can't override/implement poly function with type parameter by function without it in scala? I tried this in java and works, so I'm very curious about why scala defined this.

Comment: It is not possible to override generic function by not generic: first of all (it is my logic, not lang specification), if it is generic it means it depends on type parameter, so in your case you have to implement all functions for all posiible types (it is impossible of cource).
However, it seems to me, that these functions (generic and not generic) have absolutely different signature for dipacther (you can notice it even in scala console). But for complete answer I recommend you @retronym :)

Answer (score 2):

The type parameter `T` being defined on the function, not on the enclosing type `Element`, it can't be 'erased' by inheritance and must be kept on the overriding function (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-members).

Moving the type parameter to `Element` definition make it work as following.

```scala
trait Element[T <: Typed] {
   def eval: Try[T]
}

trait Typed

case class NumberLike(n: Long) extends Typed

case class SomeElement(n: Long) extends Element[NumberLike] {
  def eval = Try {
    NumberLike(n)
  }
}
```

Or using a type member:

```scala
trait Element {
   type T <: Typed
   def eval: Try[T]
}

trait Typed

case class SomeElement(n: Long) extends Element {
  type T = NumberLike
  def eval = Try {
    NumberLike(n)
  }
}
```

Comment: This would mean that all things that extend Element must supply a type parameter for Element.

Comment: I prefer the 2nd one. I think it should ready `T <: Typed` though.

Comment: And that's not workaround, there is no other way the compiler can check the type safety of `T` in subtype. As in `class A[T] { def foo[T]: T = ??? }` where (local) type parameter `T` of `foo` is not the same as `T` of type `A`, unless it get unified (`class A[T] { def foo: T = ??? }` | `class A { type T; def foo: T = ??? }` ...).

Comment: Maybe add the link to "matching members" and delete "For me". http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-members

Answer (score 0):

Since someone has given a solution, I'm trying to explain why.

In java, something like this is illegal:

```
class A {
  <T> T f() {return null;}
  Object f() {return null;}
}
```

But in scala, it's legal:

```
class A {
  def f[T](): T = ???
  def f(): Any = ???
}
```

The main difference is that: scala treat 2 methods with same name and parameters list different if one of them has type parameter and another don't.(I think the signature of scala method include type parameters, correct me if I was wrong :) )

So in your case, you can't overwrite a method with type parameter by a normal method.(they have different signatures)

I'm not sure which one is better, personally I prefer the scala rule :)